# Windows 7 - volume change feedback

Tags: windows-7, audio, osd

I am using windows 7. I also use Linux Mint every now and than. One of the nice features of Mint is that it has volume feedback when pressing the volume buttons on the keyboard/laptop. I would see a volume indicator on the screen and hear a sound corresponding to the set volume. In windows I have neither. I can get volume feedback by click on speaker icon in the toolbar and than dragging the slider around. I would like for windows 7 to give me some visual and audible feedback when adjusting the volume. How can I do this. is it even possible without 3rd party tools?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Displaying a volume level indicator is usually part of the audio card driver or its accompanying software. But all is not lost.

Matthew Malensek has created [3RXV](http://matthew.malensek.net/projects/) which is a skinnable, volume control application which aims to [emulate the volume display](http://matthew.malensek.net/software/documentation/3RVX.html) of Mac OS on Windows. Addictive Tips has [a tutorial](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/on-screen-volume-control-indicator-for-windows/) on how to get the most out of the application, but seems as if the application itself is fairly straight forward.

Addition: If you want to change the default sound for a skin, overwrite the `sound.wav` file found under the skin's folder.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The sound when changing the volume is not so nice. Can I change it to the sound the mac makes?

Comment: Added how to change the sound for a skin to the main answer. See if that helps. :-)

Comment: @Vader Alternate solution: [Volume2](http://irzyxa.deviantart.com/art/Volume2-is-an-advanced-Windows-volume-control-270152280)

Comment: @JSanchez thanks. I will stick with 3RVX because I like the skins more.